# Two ranges with \animatevalue

Tags: beamer

I want to make a fade-in then a fade-out effect in one frame environment.

Expected: TEXT starts red, then fades out, then returns red

Observed: first 4 slides are empty, then during 5-8 slides TEXT fades in

What should I do to get proper result?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, 14pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}
    \newcount\ww
    \begin{frame}
        \animate<2-8>
        \animatevalue<1-4>{\ww}{100}{0}
        \animatevalue<5-8>{\ww}{0}{100}
        {\color{red!\the\ww!white} TEXT}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load pgf anyway so you could do

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, 14pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}
    \newcount\ww
    \begin{frame}
        \animate<2-8>
        \animatevalue<1-8>{\ww}{0}{200}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myopa}{abs(100-\the\ww)}
        {\color{red!\myopa!white} TEXT}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an observation that may help to understand why your proposal does not quite work as desired. Add typeouts to your MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, 14pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}
    \newcount\ww
    \begin{frame}
        \animate<2-8>
        \animatevalue<1-4>{\ww}{100}{0}
        \typeout{before:\the\ww}
        \animatevalue<5-8>{\ww}{0}{100}
        \typeout{after:\the\ww}
        {\color{red!\the\ww!white} TEXT}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This yields the output

```
before:67
after:0
[2]
before:34
after:0
[3]
before:0
after:0
[4]
before:0
after:0
[5]
before:0
after:33
[6]
before:0
after:66
[7]
before:0
after:100
```

meaning that the second `\animatevalue`, i.e. `\animatevalue<5-8>{\ww}{0}{100}`, overwrites the counter from the first one. You could of course resolve this with basic TeX only, e.g.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43, 14pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}
    \newcount\ww
    \newcount\www
    \newcount\wwww
    \begin{frame}
        \animate<2-8>
        \animatevalue<1-4>{\ww}{100}{0}
        \animatevalue<5-8>{\www}{0}{100}
        \ifnum\the\ww>0
        \wwww=\ww
        \else
        \wwww=\www
        \fi
        {\color{red!\the\wwww!white} TEXT}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works, but this will IMHO be more complicated than using pgf, which you load anyway.

Comment: Aw. That didn't came to my mind to make such a hacky workaround because I got used to "There is always a neat way to do LaTeX properly but only few know it". Yep, this solves the problem (thank you), but I want to see whether there exists a 'right' way to do this.

Comment: @StaticZero Some time ago I fought about this and gave up but it is quite possible that someone finds a better and short solution. I think that the second `\animatevalue<5-8>`, i.e. `\animatevalue<5-8>{\ww}{0}{100}`, overwrites the counter from the first one, but I may be wrong. So you could make it work with if statements but this may not necessarily be simpler (but I am not sure).